# std::find_if on std::vector of custom objects with duplicate data

Tags: c++, vector, std

Consider the following scenario:

```
typedef struct myStruct
{
    int cn;
    std::string dn;
} MyStruct; 

int main()
{
    std::vector<MyStruct> v;
    // fill some data
    ...
    ...
    int c = 1;
    std::vector<MyStruct>::iterator it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
                 [c](const MyStruct& m) -> bool { return m.cn == c; });

    // use 'it' to do stuff
}
```

If `v` contains `MyStruct` objects such that the member variable `cn` has a value `c (=1)` in more than one entries, how to handle that scenario? As `std::find_if()` returns an iterator to the first element in the range, what about the rest?

Comment: `_MyStruct` is reserved, and the whole `typedef struct ...` business is pointless in C++. Where do people get the idea of using those ugly reserved names anyway?

Comment: So much for creating a MCVE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find_if` find first element in range and returns iterator to it. For find all you can either write loop, that will search each-time from `it`:

```
std::vector<MyStruct>::iterator it = v.begin();
while (it != v.end())
{
    it = std::find_if(it, v.end(),
    [c](const MyStruct& m) -> bool { return m.cn == c; });
    if (it != v.end())
    {
       // process founded item
       ++it;
    }
}
```

or you can sort your sequence and use [equal_range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) algorithm, that will return `std::pair` of iterators.

Comment: or use `copy_if` to write all the matches to a new sequence.

Answer (score 3):

With the current Standard library, you have to write a either a loop over `std::find_if` with a predicate (lambda if you can use C++11/14), or use `std::copy_if` to copy every match to a new sequence.

When the [**Ranges proposal**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4382.pdf) becomes available (in a Technical Specification along with C++17), things get much easier, e.g. you will be able to write one single chain of composable views and actions:

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace ranges;

int main()
{
    auto const is_even = [](auto x) { return x % 2 == 0; };
    auto const print = [&](auto x) { std::cout << x << ","; return x; };

    std::vector<int> v { 1, 11, 42, 57, 63, 72 };
    v | view::filter(is_even) | action::transform(print); 
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e70860bcb999204f)</kbd>** (already works with the [**range-v3 library**](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3)).